# Getting Error But console.log still working

Tags: javascript

I am learning to use API. And I am trying to make a news website using API. The API I am using is returning an array of articles. I am trying to destructure the title from it. It is working fine if I am destucturing a particular index of articles array. But whenever I am using a for loop the titles are getting printed in the console. (As i have used a console.log() you will understand on seeing the code). But at the same time it is giving a error-

````
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'title' of 'data.articles[i]' as it is undefined.
    at Object.fetchCotent (index.js:26)
    at index.js:19```
````

Here is the code I am using:

```
var newsAccordion = document.getElementById("newsAccordion");

let news = {
  apiKey: "731e3bdfcdb34ffd977ebbbec9bf1d15",
  fetchNews: function () {
    fetch(
      "https://newscatcher.p.rapidapi.com/v1/latest_headlines?lang=en&country=IN&media=True",
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "x-rapidapi-key":
            "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          "x-rapidapi-host": "newscatcher.p.rapidapi.com",
        },
      }
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.fetchCotent(data);
      });
  },
  fetchCotent: (data) => {
    size = data.articles.length;
    let newsHtml = "";
    for (var i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
      const { title } = data.articles[i];
      console.log(title);

      let newsCard = `<div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">
                              ${title}
                            </p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">
                              Go somewhere
                            </a>
                          </div>
                        </div>;`;
      newsHtml += newsCard;
    }
    newsAccordion.innerHTML = newsHtml;
  },
};
```

My question is if there is an error in the previous line how console.log is working, what is cause of the error and how can I solve it?

Comment: It is possible that the articles' index does not start with 0, so changing the initial value of i to 1 in the for loop should help. To confirm this, try to console.log the data.

Comment: @iismaell no it starts with 0

Comment: @BIJANROY As the above comment says, you should console log `data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size variable has the length of the articles array.

`size = data.articles.length;`

And in the `for` loop you are starting to iterate from index `0` and ending at `i<=size`. Since the array index starts from zero, so the proper condition should be `i<size` and not `i<=size`, therefore, the `data.articles[i]` when i = size will be `undefined`.

> My question is if there is an error in the previous line how console.log is working, what is cause of the error and how can I solve it?

The articles is undefined when i = size, until that all of your array titles got printed to the console.

```js
const articles = [{
  title: 'one'
}, {
  title: 'two'
}, {
  title: 'three'
}, {
  title: 'four'
}];

for(let i=0; i <= articles.length; i++) {
  console.log(`Article title at the index ${i}`, articles[i].title);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look around these...(not commenting bcz **repu<50**)

- Check that each article from the api has the "title" property. If a single one doesn't have it it might return undefined.
- try console logging the data.
- You can set a default value for title, if "title" doesn't exits:
  `const { title = "My title" } = data.articles[i];`